# Cannot read property 'tonotation()' of undefined

Tags: javascript, tone.js

I'm building a simple web tool that uses Javascript to create an instrument. I am using the Tone.js framework to do so. I am having issues with a chord function I built right now. I am using a barely-modified version of functions found on [this site](https://www.guitarland.com/MusicTheoryWithToneJS/PlayChords.html), but for some reason every time I call the function makeChordArray it returns the error "Cannot read property 'toNotation' of undefined". But toNotation() is defined in Tone.js. And I specifically define toneTime in the function. I am sure this is simple, but I cannot figure out the issue here. Relevant code below:

```
var melodysynth = new Tone.PolySynth(6, Tone.Synth, {
    oscillator : {
        type : "square"
    }
  }).toMaster();
  //set the attributes using the set interface
melodysynth.set("detune", -1200);

var familyOfTriads = [[0,4,7],[0,3,7],[0,3,6],[0,4,8]];

function makeChordArray(root, chordFormula, timeInterval) {
    var indexMIDI
    var aChord = [];
    var timeAndChord = [];
    var toneTime = 0;
    var chordArray = [];
    for(let i=0; i<chordFormula.length; i++) {
        for(let j=0; j<chordFormula[i].length; j++) {
            // add the root to each chord tone
            indexMIDI = chordFormula[i][j] + Number(root);
            // tranlate to a pitch/octave name
            aChord.push(MIDI_NUM_NAMES[indexMIDI]);
        }
        j = 0;
        // create add time and chord together
        timeAndChord.push(toneTime.toNotation());
        timeAndChord.push(aChord);
        chordArray.push(timeAndChord);
        // now calc the time value for next time
        toneTime = toneTime.add(timeInterval);
        // clear the arrays;
        aChord = [];
        timeAndChord = [];
    }
    return chordArray;
}

function playFamilyOfTriads(root, synth) {

  // this line is hardwired to the familyOfTriads global array,
  // that will need to change to make this a more useful function
  var myChords = makeChordArray(root, familyOfTriads, '2m');

var chordPart = new Tone.Part(function(time, chord){
    synth.triggerAttackRelease(chord, "2m", time);
}, myChords ).start(0);

chordPart.loop = true;
chordPart.loopStart = "0:0";
chordPart.loopEnd = "8:0";

var tempo = 60;
Tone.Transport.bpm.value = tempo;
Tone.Transport.start("+0.1");

}

playFamilyOfTriads(60, melodysynth);
```

Comment: Couple of problems here... `toneTime` is, as far as I can tell, a `Number` (at least when you initialise it to `0`). Is that expected to have a `toNotation()` method? As for your actual problem, at a guess, I'd say `toneTime.add()` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/13.8.25/Time.html), it seems you want `var toneTime = Tone.Time(0)` but even then, there is no `add()` method so what docs are you looking at?

Comment: Ah, this is really helpful. So the page that I took this code from does have just a number there for ToneTime as you noted. But the source code for that page correctly defines that line as:     `var toneTime = Tone.Time("0");`

So that actually solves my first problem. But you're also correct that `toneTime` does not have a function `add()`. Nonetheless, the source code DOES have that line still. So I am now getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: toneTime.add is not a function`

Comment: I'm looking at the tutorial on this website: https://www.guitarland.com/MusicTheoryWithToneJS/PlayChords.html. Their code runs on the site so presumably they got it to work?

Comment: The site you're looking at is using an old version (`r11`). See the release notes for [`r12`](https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/releases/tag/r12) regarding the breaking changes